# Best approach to make non component functions update redux state without passing store.dispatch() as a parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

So I'm creating my first ReactJS/redux application and I need a little guidance.

I've created a generic `apiFetch<T>(method, params) : Promise<T>` function which lives in `api/apiClient.ts`. (Not a React component, but called indirectly from React components)

Basically every `fetchEmployee`/`fetchSettings`/`fetchWhatever` method in `rpc/rpcMethods.ts` calls this `apiFetch<T>()` function.

What I'd like to achieve is a statusbar in my app which shows how many concurrent api calls are active. I therefore created a redux `rpcStatusSlice` based on [this redux example](https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux-typescript/blob/master/template/src/features/counter/counterSlice.ts).

Can I make `apiFetch<T>()` update the slice **without** passing the `UseAppDispatch()` result as a parameter from my React components?

If I directly import the store in `apiClient.ts` and call the state modifying functions from rpcStatusSlice on it I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
    at Module.default (bundle.js:1444:42)
    at Module../src/store/store.ts (bundle.js:1957:67)
    at Module.options.factory (bundle.js:90091:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:89541:33)
    at fn (bundle.js:89762:21)
    at Module../src/api/apiClient.ts (bundle.js:206:70)
    at Module.options.factory (bundle.js:90091:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:89541:33)
    at fn (bundle.js:89762:21)
    at Module../src/api/rpcMethods.ts (bundle.js:288:68)
```

apiFetch.ts:

```
import { store } from "../store/store";
import { incrementByAmount } from "../store/features/rpcStatusSlice";

export function apiFetch<T>(method: string, params: any): Promise<T> {
  store.dispatch(incrementByAmount(1));
  return fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    mode: "cors",
    redirect: "follow",
    body: JSON.stringify(getApiRequest(method, params)),
  })
    .then(etc)
```

./store/features/rpcStatusSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../store';

export interface ActiveRequest{
  requestType: string;
}

export interface RpcStatus {
  activeRequestsCount: 0;
  activeRequests: ActiveRequest[];
}

export interface RpcStatusState {
  value: RpcStatus;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
}

const initialState: RpcStatusState = {
  value: {
    activeRequestsCount: 0,
    activeRequests: []
  },
  status: 'idle',
};

export const rpcStatusSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'rpcstatus',
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.value.activeRequestsCount += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value.activeRequestsCount -= 1;
    },
    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value.activeRequestsCount += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = rpcStatusSlice.actions;

// The function below is called a selector and allows us to select a value from
// the state. Selectors can also be defined inline where they're used instead of
// in the slice file. For example: `useSelector((state: RootState) => state.rpcstatus.value)`
export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.rpcStatus.value.activeRequestsCount;

export default rpcStatusSlice.reducer;
```

./store/store.ts

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rpcStatusReducer from './features/rpcStatusSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    rpcStatus: rpcStatusReducer
  },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

Comment: "If I directly import the store in apiClient.ts and call the state modifying functions from rpcStatusSlice on it I get this error:" Please show the code that goes with this verbal description.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I added some more of the relevant code including the slice and store definition.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to update the state in `apiState` instead of in the components that call it? Also, do you or will you have slices for each data type, e.g. employeeSlice? The clearest approach I see, especially given the example you referenced, is to have a thunk for each data fetch, and use the thunk status cases to update `activeRequestsCount`

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make apiFetch() update the slice without passing the UseAppDispatch() result as a parameter from my React components?

This sounds like you want `apiFetch()` to do two things:

1. Make an HTTP request.
2. Update redux state.

This violates the separation of concerns principle. Instead, call `apiFetch()` from a thunk that then updates redux state.

Answer (score 0):

If your StatusBar component is the *only* consumer of the number of concurrent api calls, I'd consider not even using redux for this. This counter is not necessarily even global state, I'd see it as volatile, local component state for the `StatusBar`. Therefore, the solution I'm proposing relies only on React. It takes advantage of the pattern of keeping state in the module scope of the apiClient. At runtime, your apiClient module exists as a singleton with its own scope (many modules importing the apiClient will always use the same instance).

This abstracts the task of counting api calls away and lets the other parts of the codebase use `apiFetch()` without worrying about the counter. No need to adjust your existing thunks etc..

```
// apiClient.ts
let incrementCounter = (): void => null;
let decrementCounter = (): void => null;

export const onRequestStart = (callback: () => void) => {
  incrementCounter = callback;
};

export const onRequestEnd = (callback: () => void) => {
  decrementCounter = callback;
};

export const apiFetch = (method, params) => {
  incrementCounter();
  // do actual api call
  return someKindOfPromise.finally(decrementCounter);
};


// StatusBar.tsx (component showing the number of concurrent api calls)
import { onRequestStart, onRequestEnd } from 'apiClient.ts';

const StatusBar = () => {
  const [numConcurrentCalls, setNumConcurrentCalls] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Tell api client to always call the following function when a request starts.
    onRequestStart(() => setNumConcurrentCalls(num => num + 1));

    // Tell api client to always call the following function when a request ends.
    onRequestEnd(() => setNumConcurrentCalls(num => num - 1));
  }, [setNumConcurrentApiCalls]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Concurrent api calls: {numConcurrentCalls}</p>
    </div>
  );        
};
```